# Getting input as string and Printing

Tags: c, string, input

I'm trying to write a mastermind program but I'm stuck with string inputs. I try get user guess and when I try to print it it gives error I don't know why here is that part of the program

```
char* UserGuess[4];

void *Guess()
{
    long i;
    printf("Enter your guess: ");
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        fgets(UserGuess, 4, stdin);

    }
    return UserGuess;       
}   
int main()
{
    int userchoice=0, i;    

    while(userchoice!=2)
    {

        Guess();
        printf("%s\n", UserGuess[0]);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `userchoice` doesn't change at all in your loop. And the call to `Guess()` is useless since you ignore the return value. `UserGuess` is an array of pointers but you seem to be using it like an array. There are too many basic issues in your code. Better read a proper text book.

Comment: userchoice is not matter at this moment I am just trying the program and why guess function is useless it is recording the data to the array and array is defined as global variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets take a look at these two lines:

```
char* UserGuess[4];

fgets(UserGuess, 4, stdin);
```

The first declares and defines `UserGuess` as an array of four *pointers to `char`*. I.e. as four strings.

The second tries to use it as an array of `char`, i.e. a single string.

This is wrong and you probably want something like

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    fgets(UserGuess[i], SOME_SIZE, stdin);
```

That of course leads to another problem, because all the pointers in `UserGuess` will be null pointers (global variables are zero-initialized, which means pointers become `NULL`). So you have to change the array definition as well:

```
char UserGuess[4][SOME_SIZE];
```

---

***Or*** you only want a single string of three character (plus the terminator)? Then you should change the definition of the array to

```
char UserGuess[4];
```

and change the output to e.g.

```
printf("%s\n", UserGuess);
```

---

Then on a somewhat related note, the [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) functions reads the newline and might add it to the string (if it fits).

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I changed it as you said but I want user to enter four colors like; red green black white the press enter and it will store it in string and when I print it like userchoice[0] will be equal to red. Is it possible to do this with your given code above ?

Comment: @HasanBilalAdak Then look at the first section of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `UserGuess` is an array of pointer-to-`char`, but all the elements, are *invalid* (`NULL`). You need to allocate memory to them before you can write into team.

That said, with `fgets()`, you need to pass the individual elements of the array.

Something like

```
char UserGuess[4][32];
```

and

```
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    fgets(UserGuess[i], 32, stdin);

}
```

can be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use scanf("%d",&n) where n is an integer instead of going this route.